# What's the fastest way to check that entry exists in database?

Tags: mysql, performance, count, exists

I'm looking for the fastest way to check that entry exists...

All my life, I did with something like this...

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `table_name`
```

Some people don't use `COUNT(id)`, but `COUNT(*)`. Is that faster?

What about `LIMIT 1`?

P.S. With `id` I meant primary key, of course.

Thanks in an advice!

Comment: It's preferred you use SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table_name

Comment: Fastest way to check a row exists in table or fastest way to check that a table in database has >0 rows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In most situations, `COUNT(*)` is faster than `COUNT(id)` in MySQL (because of how grouping queries with `COUNT()` are executed, it may be optimized in future releases so both versions run the same). But if you only want to find if at least one row exists, you can use `EXISTS`

simple:

```
( SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table_name ) > 0
```

a bit faster:

```
( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name ) > 0
```

much faster:

```
EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table_name)
```

Comment: Can I use `WHERE `x` = 'abc'` with these example? What about `LIMIT 1`? Maybe it does boost performance as well?

Comment: You can use any complex condition inside any of these (WHERE,  multiple JOINs). If `id` is not nullable, all 3 are equivalent (either of them return TRUE or FALSE at same situation).

Comment: `EXISTS` actually works like `LIMIT 1`. When one row is found that matches the criteria, it stops searching for more.

Answer (score 5):

If you aren't worried about accuracy, `explain select count(field) from table` is incredibly fast.

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/

This link explains the difference between `count(*)` and `count(field)`. When in doubt, `count(*)`

As for checking that a table is not empty...

`SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table)`