# SQL - Check if string already exists in table field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with an 'url' column - VARCHAR(2000)

So it can be a very long string comparison

What is the best way to check if an url is already in the table

I need a reliable and optimized query

### Option 1

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE url='http://www.example.com'
```

and check if result is 0

### Option 2

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE url LIKE 'http://www.example.com'
```

and check if result is 0

### Or something else ?

**Note**: I am using MySQL but you are free to give answers for other DBMS

Comment: If there are no wildcard characters, there's no difference between `=` and `LIKE`. Just make sure you have an index on the `url` column, and both versions should be very efficient.

Comment: What is wrong with what you have?

Comment: I will change count(*) in 1 so return only first

Comment: @Becuzz I'm just curious about what's more efficient

Comment: Minor comment, = comparison doesn't (always) care about trailing blanks (depending on setting), but like does. So = != LIKE...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the fastest way to check that entry exists in database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569137/whats-the-fastest-way-to-check-that-entry-exists-in-database)

Answer (score 5):

If i want to know if a value *exists* i use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE url='http://www.example.com/test.html?arg=blabla')
       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS UrlExists
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
SELECT 1
FROM mytable
WHERE url = 'http://www.example.com'
LIMIT 1
```

This will stop searching as soon as it finds the first match. Then just test whether the query returns 0 or 1 rows.

If you have an index on the `url` column, all variants of the query will be pretty similar in performance. But if there's no idex, this should be about as fast as you can get. It will do a linear search, but will only have to search the entire table if the URL doesn't exist.

Comment: is LIMIT 1 necessary if there is SELECT 1? i'am not so sure ...

Comment: Yes, it's needed. Otherwise, it will return as many rows of `1` as there are matching URLs in the table, so it has to scan for all of them.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers do not explain the problem with your versions.  Your two formulations are equivalent and equally bad.  The problem is the `count(*)` which has to find all matches to the url before it can return a count.  However, for your problem, you don't need the count but merely a flag indicating existence.

The best solution starts with an index on `url`.  Both `=` and `like` can take advantage of the index, so there should be minimal performance differences between them.

Then Barmar's approach or Tim's approach will work very well.